# How to add a location filter to a php/mysql web application

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, json

I'm building a web application where businesses can log onto and post information about there business. When a "user" visits the web application, I want to able to get the user's address and store it in a mysql database. When that user visits the web application home page, I want to be able to retrieve and list all of the businesses that are stored in my database, within a 30 mile radius. I also want to give the user the option of refining the list of businesses to a distance that they can specify with a jquery slider. In other words, if they wanted to see all of the businesses within a 10 mile radius, they could slide the slider to 10 miles and the businesses would be updated asynchronously. I've searched the web and haven't really been able to find a solid solution so I was hoping that maybe someone here on SO that has come across this in their own experience, could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to those good suggestions, if you want to roll your own, check out:

https://www.dougv.com/2009/03/27/getting-all-zip-codes-in-a-given-radius-from-a-known-point-zip-code-via-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo and google search engines both provides this options. Just need to explore. I explored the same when i was experiencing yahoo pipes. Its one technology you can surely look around and explore for a solution as how they are searching for the data. You can use the same.

Google maps also has the option to provide such data. Unfortunately i didn't use it much so cant share u existing code or so. But sure to have seen this way.